# GCC structure variable assignment optimization and PLT reference

Tags: c, gcc

I need some help for GCC optimization behavior which inserts call to `memcpy` when it detects that there is a structure variable assignment.

I have below sample code:

```
struct foo_t {
        int x[1048576];
} *foo0, *foo1;

void bar(struct foo_t* foo)
{
        *foo1 = *foo;
}

int main()
{
        return 0;
}

# /usr/src/gcc-6.1.0/build/bin/gcc -fPIE -S b.c
```

This leads to GCC compiler issuing a call to `memcpy@PLT()` in function bar1.

I want to create a position independent executable from this source and run this on a secure environment which implements ASLR and the loader disallows any binary
which has PLT/GOT based relocations.

I have tried with option like `-fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns` but even with this option, if `-fPIE` flag is present I see that there is reference to `memcpy@PLT`.

I have even tried options like `-fno-plt` and `-mstringop-strategy=loop` but I do not want to use the output program generated with these options.

My problem is not with memcpy but with PLT portion; I want GCC to generate reference to `memcpy` (and not to `memcpy@PLT`) in a position independent executable when it detects that there is structure variable assignment.

I have also tried by putting hidden visibility for this file but there is same PLT reference in this case also.

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
```

Does GCC always insert call to `memcpy@PLT` for position independent executables when it detects that there is a structure variable assignment?
Is it possible to instruct GCC to insert `memcpy` with `-fPIE` flag?

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` is a function with external linkage. In a position-independent executable it can only be referred to either via the PLT or GOTPCREL (`-fno-plt`).

The only other option is to have `memcpy` inlined into the caller.

Comment: From page `https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility`; it seems that the visibility attribute is specified to generate optimal code; in this case, call to memcpy instead of setting up PLT references should have been optimal operation as I am providing the memcpy implementation and not relying on stdlib (I am compiling my program with -ffreestanding and -fnostdlib)

Answer (score -1):

Do not use assign operator for whole structures and unions, otherwise it is very probable that the memcpy will be called.

BTW you need to recompile the whole standard library if you use any of its functions in the position independent code, or need to rewrite the ones you use.